# What's the best strategy for winning while using all 3 stations in Ticket to Ride Europe?

Tags: online, ticket-to-ride-europe

Ticket to Ride Europe pocket edition has an achievement that I just can't get! It's winning using all 3 stations during the game. Can anyone suggest any strategies on any of the following:

- Should I play with 3 or 4 bot players? (You can't use double tracks with just 3)
- Should I select the 20+ pt "long route" and try to complete it?
- Should I place the stations at the very end? The bot players keep ending the game before I get a chance to establish the stations. If I place the stations earlier, it's hard to keep adding new destination tickets.

Answer (score 4):

Play with 2 or 4 bots. You'll be needing stations more with more competition for routes. Why 2? because you don't get the second half of the doubles without 4 players total. This means that to win, you'll more likely need to make more connections through occupied chunks.

If winning cleanly, grab some tickets, and take one or two that you can connect by dropping a station.